# How to debug org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender class?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jms

I am trying to run the scenario in http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html .

I have done the necessary changes but my application does not start. It gets stuck on start up. I need to way to debug the "org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender" class.

There are debug logs in the class, but how to enable them in log4j.properties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own custom log4j appender with the same code as "org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender" and changed the debug logs to System.out.println statements as a work around.